# Why does Google document lock itself?

Tags: google-docs

I use Ubuntu 11. When I open or create a Google document (.doc), I can't edit it but after a while I can. When I open it, it's "locked" and the keystrokes don't react. Anyone else seen this strange problem? The problem does not appear with MS Windows.

Answer (score 1):

This problem happens to me sometimes on my Ubuntu (its a laptop). This usually happens as Google Docs is trying to establish a connection between your computer and Google's servers, so that whatever you type can be saved automatically.

It is "locked" as a safety measure in case a connection cannot be established fast enough and you are about to close the document that you have already been working on (i.e. added content).